# Find all columns in a Pervasive database

Tags: database, pervasive-sql

I want to find all the columns with a name that includes a specific string using PSQL in a Pervasive database. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query the `X$Field` table for your string.  Something like:

```
select file.xf$name, field.xe$name from x$field field 
join x$file file on xe$file = xf$id
where xe$name like '%some string%'
```

This query should work for both original and v2 (long metadata) databases but would only work if you have the DDFs (`FILE.DDF`, `FIELD.DDF`, and `INDEX.DDF` at a minimum) and have a PSQL database setup pointing to the DDFs.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like this is useful.